# read a file and save as a matrix

Tags: c, arrays

i have a file like that :

```
1 100
2 200
3 300
4 400
1
```

i want to save it as a matrix and i want to save NULL if there is no second number !

i tried to write the program but it does not work correctly !

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int k=0 ,i,j , arr[100][100];
FILE *in= fopen("file.txt","r");
char line[1000]; 
while(fgets(line,1000,in) !=NULL) k++;
fgets(line,1000,in);
for (i=0;i<k;i++){
    for (j=0;j<2;j++){
        int tmp ;
        fscanf(in ,"%d", &tmp) ;
        arr[i][j] = tmp ;
    }
}
fclose(in);
return 0; }
```

Comment: You cannot _store_ the macro `NULL` into an integer. And you should not store its value in an integer in general.

Comment: you need `rewind`.

Comment: and use `int **arr;` instaed of `int arr[100][100];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two major problems:

The first is that the first loop will read *all* lines, even the one with the single number on the line. That means the lonely `fgets` call will not do anything, and more importantly that the value of `k` will be wrong.

The second problem is that once you read all data from the file, you don't go back to the beginning of the file, instead you continue to try and read from beyond the end of the file.

The first problem can be solve by skipping the second `fgets` call, and decreasing `k` by one.

The second problem can be solved by calling [`rewind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) after you counted the number of lines.

---

Also when you actually read the numbers, you don't need the inner loop, just do e.g.

```
scanf("%d %d", &arr[i][0], &arr[i][1]);
```

Actually, you don't need the first line-counting loop at all, you can do it all in a single loop, by using `fgets` and `sscanf` and then checking the return value of `sscanf`. So your program could look something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int values[100][2];
    FILE *input = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    size_t entries = 0;

    if (input != NULL)
    {
        char buffer[40];
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), input) != NULL && entries < 100)
        {
            int res = sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &values[entries][0], &values[entries][1]);
            if (res <= 1 || res == EOF)
            {
                // Read the last line with only one number, or an error happened
                values[entries][0] = 0;
                values[entries][1] = 0;
                break;
            }

            ++entries;
        }

        if (ferror(input))
        {
            printf("Error reading file\n");
        }

        fclose(input);
    }

    // All done, the number of "records" or "entries" is in the variable entries

    // Example code: print the values
    for (size_t i = 0; i < entries; ++i)
        printf("Line %d: %d %d\n", i + 1, values[i][0], values[i][1]); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ÐiffëřëņtĞîRl Updated the code to handle `sscanf` not returning `2` differently. But you have to elaborate on what you mean be "recording 1 with NULL".`NULL` is a null ***pointer***, you should not assign it to an integer variable. And you should really try to think a little bit yourself, I really don't like writing your code for you, that won't make you actually *learn* anything but copy-pasting.

Comment: i hope to get output matrix like that : 
[ 1 100 ; 2 200 ; 3 300; 4 400 ; 1 NULL];
but anyway i will try to do

Comment: Nice answer: minor question: Why use `if (res <= 1 || res == EOF)` vs `if (res <= 1)` or `if (res != 2)` or ...?  Some sort of clarity emphasizes?  Note: suggest `printf("Line %zu: %d %d\n", ...`